# Can I skip the Keras Embedding Layer if I already transformed the data to Word2Vec (Google News 300 format)?

Tags: lstm, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

Trying to do sentiment analysis with an LSTM NN. I think I understand what the embedding layer does: map each word to a fixed-di-vector.
However, previously, for each text sample, I transformed each word to a 300 length vector, and computed the mean vector.

So now, my data is already in a fixed 300-di vector. Can I skip the keras embedding layer, and simply attach the data to a dense/LSTM layer?

Thank you in advance for replying.